# Can't authorize computer to play iTunes songs

Tags: itunes, authorization

I purchased music on my old computer with different email addresses ans passwords. The computer died and I need the old passwords to play some of my music. Is there an email address for iTunes support where I can request my old passwords? I have tried calling the support number but they could not resolve the issue.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you still remember and have access to the email addresses you used, you can go to this page to reset your passwords: [Forgot my Password](https://iforgot.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSiForgot.woa/wa/iforgot?app_type=ext&app_id=93&returnURL=https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa&language=US-EN)

Comment: I have tried that but still get the "this computer is not authorised to play" box when I try and play certain tracks. I try typing in what I think was the relevant password or try setting a new password but when I try to play the tracks the same box comes up again. I think I need to confirm my original passwords and try using them but itunes weren't particularly helpful over the phone, I wondered if there was an address I could email?

Comment: I believe that iTunes is only allowed to be authorized to one account at a time. If you are using multiple ones, then it will only play tracks from whichever account iTunes is currently authorized in.

The best way that you could work around this situation is to log into your multiple accounts one at a time, and to convert the tracks purchased with that account into a DRM-free format (such as MP3.)

Answer (score 0):

Within iTunes, choose the `Help > Apple Service and Support` menu item. This takes you to the Apple ExpressLane support interface in your web browser. Select your product (iTunes), feature area (iTunes Store), and support category (Account Management). Answer the on-screen questions and you should be able to submit a message for iTunes Store support.

If you don't have access to the original email accounts, it will be very difficult to retrieve or reset the passwords. Typically, a password reset link is emailed, and if you can't retrieve the email, you wouldn't be able to retrieve or reset the password.